# How to label data from other dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data such as below:

```
rf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],'B': [5, 6, 7, 5, 9],'C': ['2a', '2b', '2b', '2c', '2c']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b','c'],'B': ['2a', '2b', '2c']})
```

I want to add 'label' to rf based on df, so the final data will be like this :

```
rf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],'B': [5, 6, 7, 5, 9],'C': ['2a', '2b', '2b', '2c', '2c'],'label': [1,0,1,0,1]})
```

Comment: what determines the label to be 0 or 1?

Comment: _I have applied some logic, but the 'label' == 1 in rf that I got is more than the amount of df record_ Please provide a [mcve]. By the way, why use 0/1 for what looks like boolean values?

Comment: @sammywemmy if one row on rf column 'A' and 'C' exist on any row on df column 'A' and 'C'

Comment: @AMC Sorry about the lack of explanation, I tried comare each one with for if looping to check, for every row rf in every row df, but somehow from around 600 record in df in rf become around 700, I don't know why I use 0/1, I usually use that for classification problem

Comment: @AMC I already delete the additional explanation because I think the problem might be in the data itself

Comment: @NabilaSekarRamadhanti I’m confused, you don’t know why you use 0 and 1? _I think the problem might be in the data itself_ Did the accepted answer not solve the issue?

Comment: @AMC , I think it's more like I don't understand the question, I'm using 1/0 instead of boolean because others using the same kind of data I used (drug-target interaction) is also using these 1/0. not actually still got 700+ data while the df record is 600+

Comment: @NabilaSekarRamadhanti _ not actually still got 700+ data while the df record is 600+_ So it isn't completely solved. Can you share more relevant information, or do you think this belongs in a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach

```
rf['label']= np.where((rf['A']+rf['C']).isin(df['A']+df['B']),1,0)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   label
0   a   5   2a  1
1   a   6   2b  0
2   b   7   2b  1
3   b   5   2c  0
4   c   9   2c  1
```